# How to get post titles by post ID and integrate with my code?

Tags: php, posts

I have function which gets menu next and previous item url. I want to get also title for them. How can I do this? This is what i have :

```
  <?php
$menu_name = 'main-menu';
$locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
$menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );
$menuitems = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->term_id, array( 'order' => 'DESC' ) );

$i=-1;
foreach ( $menuitems as $item ):

    $i++;

  $id = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu_item_object_id', true );
  $page = get_page( $id );
  $link = get_page_link( $id );

    $linkarray.=$id.",";
    $urlarray.=$link.",";

  if ($id==$post->ID){
    $previd=$i-1;
    $nextid=$i+1;
  }
endforeach;

$linkarray=explode(',',$linkarray);
$urlarray=explode(',',$urlarray);

$nextid=$urlarray[$nextid];
if (empty($nextid)){
    $nextid=$urlarray[0];
}
$previd=$urlarray[$previd];
if (empty($previd)){
    $previd=$urlarray[$i];
}
?>

<a href="<?php echo $nextid; ?>">Next Item</a>
<a href="<?php echo $previd; ?>">Previous Item</a>
```

Destination point is to replace 'next item' and 'previous item' with wp_nav_menu's next and prev item titles. Is that possible with this function? Any answer will be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a post title by ID you need: `get_the_title( $id );`.

You can integrate this into your code using a similar method for how this has been done for the URL's with $link, but that's basically a PHP coding question, so it's best to get as far as you can with the code and then post again if you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks Man! Got it work!

Answer (score 0):

```
      <?php
      $menu_name = 'primary';
      $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
      $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );
      $menuitems = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->term_id, array( 'order' => 'DESC' ) 
      );

      $i=-1;
      foreach ( $menuitems as $item ):

        $i++;

        $id = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu_item_object_id', true );
        $page = get_page( $id );
        $link = get_page_link( $id );
        $title = get_the_title( $id );

        $linkarray.=$id.",";
        $urlarray.=$link.",";
        $titlearray.=$title.",";

        if ($id==$post->ID){
          $previd=$i-1;
          $nextid=$i+1;
          $titleid=$i+1;
        }
      endforeach;

      $linkarray=explode(',',$linkarray);
      $urlarray=explode(',',$urlarray);
      $titlearray=explode(',',$titlearray);

      $titleid=$titlearray[$titleid];
      $nextid=$urlarray[$nextid];
      if (empty($nextid)){
          $nextid=$urlarray[0];
      }
      $previd=$urlarray[$previd];
      if (empty($previd)){
          $previd=$urlarray[$i];
      }
      ?>

<?php echo $titleid; ?>
```

**This is the edited working version, in case if somebody will need.**